Different traceId in single request with use StreamingResponseBody (Spring Boot 3, micrometer)
Different traceId in single request with use StreamingResponseBody
in pom:
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.ttddyy.observation</groupId>
  <artifactId>datasource-micrometer-spring-boot</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
  <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
  <version>${micrometer-registry-prometheus.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
  <artifactId>micrometer-tracing</artifactId>
  <version>${micrometer-tracing.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
   <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave</artifactId>
</dependency>

I am trying to call an endpoint controller
Example 1:
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RestController
@Slf4j
public class MyController implements MyApi {
private final MyRepository repository;

@Override
public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> getData(String id, String date) {
    StreamingResponseBody responseBody = outputStream -> {
        repository.getFile(id, date, outputStream);
    };
    return ResponseEntity
        .status(HttpStatus.OK)
        .body(responseBody);
    }
}

I got different traceId for call controller and call repository.
But if it looks like this:
Example 2:
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RestController
@Slf4j
public class MyController implements MyApi {
private final MyRepository repository;

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> getData(String id, String date) {

    repository.getFile(id, date, OutputStream.nullOutputStream());

    return ResponseEntity
        .status(HttpStatus.OK)
        .body(responseBody);
    }
}

Here the trace is the same
StreamingResponseBody creates a new traceId, but I need the same traceId for this one request, and I need example 1
Example method in repository:
  @SneakyThrows
    public void getFile(String id, String data, OutputStream outputStream) {
        try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
             CallableStatement cs = connection.prepareCall(CALL_PROCEDURE)) {
            cs.setDate(1, Date.valueOf(data));
            cs.registerOutParameter(2, Types.LONGVARCHAR);
            cs.execute();
            try (Reader reader = cs.getCharacterStream(2);
                 OutputStreamWriter os = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream)) {
                reader.transferTo(os);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("get error", e);
        }
    }

